# Remove autocomplete dropdown options when the submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

i used the jquery-ui autocomplete for my search bar. However, i noticed that whenever i type in something and click enter without choosing any of the options given by the autocomplete feature, the autocomplete dropdown words remainthere.

Is there a way that i can automatically close the autocomplete dropdown words when i click the submit button for my search bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "close" ); 
use this code in the click function of the button...